# Blazor - searching by strings concatenation

Tags: c#, blazor

Using Blazor, I have a model which contains, among other things, two properties: FirstName and LastName. As a result, I receive a grid with two separated columns with first and last name. Searching feature for the records is enabled.
Lets assume that grid contains a record with first name: John and last name: Smith. When I search for "John", the record is found, when I search for "Smith" - the record is also found. But when I am trying to search for "John Smith", I receive: "There are no items to display".
I guess why it happens, but I would like to ask if there is any workaround to create a column with concatenation of first and last name (this column should be hidden) and enable to search by both values (get the result for: "John Smith"). I read the documentation and tried to add "Not connected column", but it does not work (I found the information that sorting and filtering will not work, but there was nothing about searching). Because the data comes from database, I would like to avoid adding a new column in database with redundant informations from other columns.
Do You have any tips, ideas or implemented workaround for this kind of problem?

Comment: Blazor doesn't have a built-in grid component (though one is planned for .NET 7.0). Your question is missing some context and it can't be answered without it.

Comment: can you show us some code that you did? what gird are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Entity Framework, you can add a [[NotMapped] property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) to the class, which returns the desired value (even though it is not mapped in the database).  For example:

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public string NameAndSurname
   {
      get => $"{FirstName} {Surname}";
   }    
}
```

Not sure what function you use to filter your users - but you should be able to use "`User.NameAndSurname`",  in the same way that "`User.FirstName`" was used.

Comment: Your answer is relevant, but it doesn't answer the whole question. The poster is asking how to apply a grid filter for a property that isn't shown as a column, but the poster hasn't explained what kind of grid they are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that suggestion. I modified my model and added new property to Grid column collection - now I am able to search by both values at the same time. But unfortunately, when I set this column as hidden, searching is not available.